# Python - ASCII encoding string in the unicode string; how to remove that 'u'?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, ascii, urlencode

When I use python module 'pygoogle' in chinese, I got url like `u'http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/\xe6\xb1\x89\xe8\xaf\xad'`

It's unicode but include ascii. I try to encode it back to utf-8 but the code be changed too.

```
a =  u'http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/\xe6\xb1\x89\xe8\xaf\xad'
a.encode('utf-8')
>>> 'http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/\xc3\xa6\xc2\xb1\xc2\x89\xc3\xa8\xc2\xaf\xc2\xad'
```

Also I try to use :

```
str(a)
```

but I got error :

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 27-32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**How can I encoding it for remove the 'u' ?**

By the way, if there is not 'u' I will get correct result like:

```
s = 'http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/\xe6\xb1\x89\xe8\xaf\xad'
print s
>>> http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/汉语
```

Comment: Are you using Python2? When I type `print a`, I get the correct output. Why does the initial 'u' bother you?

Comment: @user2560053: did you try printing `a`? That's not Chinese text you get, that's `http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/æ±è¯­­­­­` (plus a 0x89 byte and U+00AD soft hyphen that you just cannot copy into a comment box), not `http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/汉语`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake); in this case those are UTF-8 bytes decoded as if they were Latin-1 bytes.

To reverse the process, encode to Latin-1 again:

```
>>> a =  u'http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/\xe6\xb1\x89\xe8\xaf\xad'
>>> a.encode('latin-1')
'http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/\xe6\xb1\x89\xe8\xaf\xad'
>>> print a.encode('latin-1')
http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/汉语
```

The `print` worked because my terminal is configured to handle UTF-8. You can get a `unicode` object again by decoding as UTF-8:

```
>>> a.encode('latin-1').decode('utf8')
u'http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/\u6c49\u8bed'
```

The ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) codec maps one-on-one to the first 255 Unicode codepoints, which is why the string contents look otherwise unchanged.

You may want to use the [`ftfy` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ftfy) for jobs like these; it handles a wide variety of text issues, including Windows codepage Mojibake where some resulting 'codepoints' are not legally encodable to the codepage. The `ftfy.fix_text()` function takes Unicode input and repairs it:

```
>>> import ftfy
>>> ftfy.fix_text(a)
u'http://zh.wikipedia.org/zh/\u6c49\u8bed'
```

Comment: The word Mojibake was new to me, thank you for enhancing my knowledge!

Comment: Thank you very much!! I got misunderstanding that 'u' means UTF-8. lol

Comment: @Andrew.T: it a `unicode` object; textual data, whereas the regular strings without a prefix are `str` objects, and consist of bytes (each character is really an integer between 0 and 255), usually representing encoded text data.

Comment: you are a God! I've been looking for this for ages!